# Starting a new Outlook 2007 Message from C# .NET

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008, interop, outlook

I'm looking for the most barebones complete example, to launch Outlook 2007 with a new message started via C# .NET (I happen to be using VS2008 .NET 3.0)

Here's what I'm trying:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;

namespace CreateMessage {

    class Program {

        static void Main ( string[] args ) {

            // Create outlook application object.
            var outlookApplication = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();

            // Create mail message.
            var newMail = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem)outlookApplication.CreateItem( Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem );
            newMail.To = "example@exam.ple";
            newMail.Subject = "Example";
            newMail.BodyFormat = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlBodyFormat.olFormatHTML;
            newMail.HTMLBody = "<p>Dear Example,</p><p>Example example.</p>";
            newMail.Display( false );

        }

    }
}
```

Here are my project refereces:

[alt text http://img4.imageshack.us/img4/9350/referencesi.jpg](http://img4.imageshack.us/img4/9350/referencesi.jpg)

Here's the intermittent exception I get (about half the time I run the program):

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException was unhandled
  Message="The message filter indicated that the application is busy. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8001010A (RPC_E_SERVERCALL_RETRYLATER))"
  Source="Interop.Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook"
  ErrorCode=-2147417846
  StackTrace:
       at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._MailItem.set_To(String To)
       at CreateMessage.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\Adam\Projects\GGS\CreateMessage\Program.cs:line 17
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(Assembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

Note: I've found many answers and examples about working with Outlook via Interop, but most of the answers don't show the using statements or are trying to do things at the next level up from what I'm shooting for.  I'm just trying to get Outlook to pop open, with a new message started, and maybe a bit of info filled in (i.e. Subject, To, etc).  Copying and pasting any of the examples I've found so far don't compile because they are snippets as opposed to a fully functioning barebones example that compiles.

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about your question, but the error message that you show indicates that you haven't added the assembly.  To do this, expand your project, and right-click on References, and select 'Add Reference...'.  Then go to the 'COM' tab (on VS2008 anyway) and locate "Microsoft Outlook 12.0 Object Library" (the specific version might be different on your machine depending on what version of Outlook is installed.)  Highlight it and then click OK.  I think that should clear your error, and will get you on the right path.

Comment: Thanks Michael.  I added the "Microsoft Outlook 12.0 Object Library", but I still get the same compilation error message: "The type or namespace name 'Outlook' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: Well I presume from your edits that you solved the compilation problem...   as for your question, when I create a new C# project with your code (all I did was cut/paste) it works just fine...  the app loads and behind it opens an Outlook email with the paramters specificed.  Maybe you should try starting over, in case you messed something up in your previous attempts.

Comment: Thanks for your help Michael.  I did have the Interop reference in there, but using the fully qualified namespace got past my initial error.  The problem I'm hitting now is the exception shown in my updated question.  The new message seem to get started before Outlook is ready and throws an "application busy" exception. (This only happens about half the time, the other half of the time, the sample executes sucessfully and the mail is generated.)